# Cannot bind argument at index 2 because the index is out of range. The statement has 1 parameters?

Tags: java, android-studio

I have an array string named `"likedAlbums_name"`

That array String contains a list of names. I would like to pass the list of names into the `whereVal` of the cursor.

When I have 1 name in the  `"likedAlbums_name"` array string, everything works fine. But if I have more than 1 name, it crash.

How to I fix that?

Thank you!!!

code:

```
likedAlbums_name = database.getLikedAlbums(); // returns a list of names
```

Code:

```
public void getSongsInAlbum() {
        String[] projections = {
                MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM,
                MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ARTIST,
                MediaStore.Audio.Albums.NUMBER_OF_SONGS,
                MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ART};

        String where = MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM + "=?";

        String[] whereVal = likedAlbums_name;

        String orderBy = MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM;

        ContentResolver contentResolver = getActivity().getContentResolver();
        Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(MediaStore.Audio.Albums.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, projections, where, whereVal, orderBy);
        if (cursor != null) {
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    newAlbum newAlbum = new newAlbum();
                    newAlbum.albumName = cursor.getString(0);
                    newAlbum.artist_Name = cursor.getString(1);
                    newAlbum.number_of_songs_in_album = cursor.getInt(2);

                    album_list.add(newAlbum);
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your where query `=?` expects only one parameter, but apparently `whereVal` contains two elements, so the query evaluator does not know, which of the elements pass on to the query and throws an error

Comment: How do I fix that exactly?

Comment: Make sure `whereVal` contains exactly one element. For instance by taking only the first one, taking a random one, taking the last one, ...

Comment: Okay, I understand that.  But isn't there a way to do it with all the items that the list?

Comment: Because I do need to display all the items that the list contains

Comment: Then you have to change your query to something like `colname=? or colname=? or colname = ?` and make sure you have as many conditions as you have elements in the list

Comment: Thank you! I will try that. The thing is, I am trying to display all the albums that the user have "heart".. I won't exactly know how many items the user "heart" or exactly which item.